# MKDirectionsRequest source and destination

Tags: swift, mapkit, deprecated

In swifts API, it says that the MKDirectionsRequest source and destination properties are available in iOS 6.0 - 8.4. It does not say there are deprecated. Does this mean it is a bad idea to continue to use these?

MKDirectionsRequest API link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsRequest_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKDirectionsRequest/initWithContentsOfURL:

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a bug in the documentation-generation mechanism. There's nothing like that in the header:

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
public class MKDirectionsRequest : NSObject {

    public var source: MKMapItem?

    public var destination: MKMapItem?
}
```

Just ignore it and use these properties in the normal way.